# How to make horizontal divider using View elemnt

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

i am trying to make a horizontal divider using View element. i wote the below code, but the problem is the divider is always of a very samll width despite the width of the View , as shown belwo, is set match_parent
please let emknow how to fix it.

**update**:

the problem is, the View is always as wide as the imageView??!! i do not know why? any explanation?

**layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl_MainTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr_Logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_Logo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/fr"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:contentDescription="@null"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="@string/str_Disc_Neigh_Device"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr_Divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/v_Divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="#90909090"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Try and make width 1 or 2 dp.

Comment: @jrsall92 i tried it but did not solve it

Comment: table layout is having its default dividers android:showDividers="yourvalue" use it instead

Comment: you can also put android:layout_weight="1" on your <View />

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did in my own app but in a linear layout, though you can give it try:

`<View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/separator1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>`

change `background` to your liking

Comment: i tried it, and still it does not work unfortunately. the problem is, the View is always as wide as the imageView??!! i do not know why? any explanation?

Comment: @rmaik because you use a relative layout. Things are going to be relative to each other. Unless you really need the relative layout try the linear one.

Comment: but i have not specified that the View should be relative to the imageView?? as far as i know, to make to elements relative to each other you have to specify it explicitly somrthing like  android:layout_toEndOf

Comment: Things are going to follow the layout that they are nested into, and that continues until you define a new one, that means that if you have something like RelativeLayout -> LinearLayout -> View, the view will obey LinearLayouts options. So if you have a root RelativeLayout only then everything under it is going to behave according to RL's options.

Answer (score 0):

Change your 2nd TableRow to LinearLayout

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tr_Divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/v_Divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="#902631"
            android:layout_span="2" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

change view background colour as you wish.

Comment: thanks, but can u please explain to me my question in the update section above?? thank you again

Comment: @rmaik, Chailds in TableRow are like Columns or Cells in a table, every cell will occupy the width based on maximum width occupied by the cell in your TableLayout. So if your image will take 10% of width in your screen and if it is the maximum with of your TableLayout, all first Child's also occupy 10% of width. because iv_Logo and v_Divider are in same column of your TableLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Table layout is having its default divider `android:showDividers="yourvalue"` you can use it instead.
also to set the divider widht by using 
`android:dividerPadding="valueindp"`